# How to Enable Intellisense in VS Code + Ionide?

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

I've created an F# (script) app via the dotnet cli using the following outlined steps. However, when I open the app/project in VS Code with Ionide, intellisense is inactive. How can I resolve this?

To create the app/project, I:

1. Created an app directory
2. Ran `dotnet new tool-manifest` and `dotnet tool install paket` and `dotnet paket restore`
3. Ran `dotnet paket init`
4. Modified `paket.dependencies`
5. Opened "project" in VS Code with Ionide

**paket.dependencies** (*Note*: I removed framework restrictions)

```
source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

storage: packages
nuget FSharp.Data
```

**Script**:

```
#r "./packages/FSharp.Core/lib/netstandard2.0/FSharp.Core.dll"
#r "./packages/FSharp.Data/lib/netstandard2.0/FSharp.Data.dll"

open System
open FSharp.Data

type research = CsvProvider<"./path/to/file", HasHeaders=true, PreferOptionals=true>
let data = research.GetSample()
```

Comment: It would be usefult to let us know the operating system you are using and the name of the F# script file that you created. If you are running on Windows, the full Visual Studio will provide you with better experience.

Comment: AS far as I know, Microsoft shelved IntelliSense and is working instead on IntelliCode which is VS  Code extension. Adding F# for intellicode is requested, but not implemented yet, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/intellicode-visual-studio-code, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues/137

Comment: You definitely need to run paket after modifying paket.dependencies, either `dotnet paket install` or `dotnet paket update`. Unless Ionide does it automatically? I don't use it that much.